# Could not find a declaration file for module 'vuetify/lib' in a fresh vue js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I created a new vue project and after that i added vuetify,

```
$ vue create my-app
$ cd my-app
$ vue add vuetify
$ npm run serve
```

then i got this error

```
ERROR in /home/ruhith/Documents/vue/file upload/fileupload/src/plugins/vuetify.ts(2,21):
2:21 Could not find a declaration file for module 'vuetify/lib'. '/home/ruhith/Documents/vue/file upload/fileupload/node_modules/vuetify/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/vuetify` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vuetify/lib';`
    1 | import Vue from 'vue';
  > 2 | import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
      |                     ^
    3 | 
    4 | Vue.use(Vuetify);
    5 | 
Version: typescript 3.8.3
Time: 2774ms
```

what did i missed here?is this a bug in vuetufy?

Comment: Add `"vuetify"` to your `types: []` array in `compilerOptions` of `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 18):

You need to add vuetify's types to tsconfig.json, like this:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["vuetify"]
  }
}
```

Taken from FAQ here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions/#questions

Comment: This doesn't fix it for me. I already had the "vuetify" in types.

Comment: Indeed, same here. Seems that this may fix it in some cases, but it's not the whole story.

Comment: I use pnpm. I had to run pnpm install --force to make it work. I do not have a definitive explanation. I got this after upgrading a few packages to their latest version and forcing my package manager to redownload all dependencies did the trick. 
If you are using npm, the command is very similar: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to adjust my `tsconfig` file adding the `moduleResolution` to it:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No matter what I did, types for color palette are missing.
So I made a decision to copy & paste the contents of `node_modules/vuetify/lib/util/colors.mjs` to my own `theme/colors.ts` and import colors from there

Ended up like so:

```
# theme/colors.ts

// from node_modules/vuetify/lib/util/colors.mjs
const red = Object.freeze({
  base: '#f44336',
  lighten5: '#ffebee',
  lighten4: '#ffcdd2',
  lighten3: '#ef9a9a',
  lighten2: '#e57373',
  lighten1: '#ef5350',
  darken1: '#e53935',
  darken2: '#d32f2f',
  darken3: '#c62828',
  darken4: '#b71c1c',
  accent1: '#ff8a80',
...
```

```
# vuetify.ts

...
import colors from '@/theme/colors'

...
const vuetify = createVuetify({
  // ... your configuration
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        colors: {
          primary: colors.red.lighten1
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
app.vueApp.use(vuetify)
```

Answer (score -4):

change the file 
node_modules->vuetify-loader->lib->plugin.js

```
class VuetifyLoaderPlugin {
  constructor (options) {
    // this.options = options || {}
    this.options = (options) ? options : {}
  }
```

Comment: modifying node_modules directly makes your build non-reproducible